# How to remove object from array depending on child condition JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to remove/ or splice objects from an array on the condition of a property. if the property string includes a string then remove that object from the array. So filter an object based on its property looping through an array of string.

**I have a object like so**

```
let obj = [
    {
        "name": "product one"
    },
    {
        "name": "product two"
    },
    {
        "name": "item one"
    },
    {
        "name": "item three"
    }
]
```

**an array**

```
let arr = ['one', 'item']
```

**So i would like my final or return object to look like**

```
[
  {
    name: "product two"
  }
]
```

I've tried for loops, double for loops, filters, and include and all fail.
One thing to note is my json file that i'm importing has over 20,000 records, so idk if thats a reason it might be failing.

```
 var intersection = obj.filter(function (e) {
      for (const word of arr) {
         return !e.name.includes(word)
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the item which is *not* included in the array, use `some` on `arr` and invert the returned Boolean:

```
const intersection = obj.filter(({ name }) => !arr.some(e => name.includes(e)));
```

If there are a lot of records, then the above approach might be too slow - this approach is more efficient:

```
const re = new RegExp(arr.join("|"));
const intersection = obj.filter(({ name }) => !re.test(name));
```

Comment: Perfect i never even thought about joining it and THEN filtering it. Thanks

Comment: No worries @FernandoB, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your loop returns after the first iteration which means that you're only checking if the element's `name` value matches the first element in the `arr` array.

Instead of a loop you can use `.some()`, here is an example:

```js
let obj = [{
    "name": "product one"
  },
  {
    "name": "product two"
  },
  {
    "name": "item one"
  },
  {
    "name": "item three"
  }
]

let arr = ['one', 'item']

const intersection = obj.filter(({
  name
}) => !arr.some(v => name.includes(v)));
console.log(intersection);
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never heard or completely forgot about the some method